# Creating a good mongodb schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working on an Inventory app for monitors, desktops, laptops, projectors, printers, scanners. So I want to ask, what would be a good structure for this? Should I create a schema each category or as one like

```
var Item = mongoose.model('Item', {
  category: { type: String, minlength: 5, required: true, trim: true },
  type: { type: String, minlength: 5, required: true, trim: true },
  brand: { type: String, minlength: 5, required: true, trim: true },
  model: { type: String, minlength: 5, required: true, trim: true },
  serial: { type: String, minlength: 5, required: true, trim: true },
  storage: { type: String, minlength: 5, required: true, trim: true },
  graphics: { type: String, minlength: 5, required: true, trim: true },
  ram: { type: String, minlength: 5, required: true, trim: true },
});
```

The ram and graphics will only be available for desktop and laptop. Is it okay to make a single schema for all or should be schema for each category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just fine ,only while doing operations on let say category is anything except desktop or laptop you can omit the property while selecting it from the document

For example

```
Item.findOne({category: "printer"}).select("-graphics -ram");
```